# MS Access VB: "OpenQuery" works, but executing the SQL statement goes on for a long time

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a query that was set up using the query wizard in access. The query does what I want it to do when I run it. It also works fine in less than one minute if I open the query directly from my VBA code, i.e.: 
* DoCmd.OpenQuery "q" & clientName & "_055UpdateAcctElg"*

clientName is a VB variable. If I duplicate the query and change the associated tables to be appropriate for the client within an individual query, this will work. But it's silly - instead, I want to use the variable within SQL code in VB.

So I view the SQL for that query in Access, copy the SQL, then paste it into VB. But now the query keeps running for more than 10 minutes, at which time my patience runs out and I interrupt it:

*'CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Audit_Master INNER JOIN Census_" & clientName & " ON (Audit_Master.AccountNum = Census_" & clientName & ".ACCOUNTNUM) AND (Audit_Master.[Case-Number] = Census_" & clientName & ".CASENUM) SET Audit_Master.LNAME = [Census_" & clientName & "]![LName], Audit_Master.FNAME = [Census_" & clientName & "]![FName] WHERE (((Audit_Master.LNAME) Is Null));"*

I've done the exact same thing with 7 other queries -- i.e. I've copied the SQL from the Access query SQL view and pasted into VB, adding a command to run it and wrapping in appropriate quotation marks.

I do not get an error message by doing this - so it makes me wonder if the SQL code is doing something different than the Access query is doing? Why does calling the query work, but executing the SQL does not?

Comment: Doesn't look like you're copying/pasting SQL - you're injecting variables into the SQL - that's dynamic SQL - which doesn't give MS-Access a chance to optiimize and compile it for faster execution. When you use the DoCmd.OpenQuery method - you're running predefined queries, giving Access db engine a chance to optimize ahead of time

Comment: Thanks. I'm rusty on terminology, but yes "dynamic SQL" it is. Guess I'll just have to be patient for now - it does work, just takes longer.

Comment: You should probably look at parameter queries - I'm pretty sure you could adapt your `CurrentDB.Execute` line into using a predefined parameter query with a querydef object. That might speed it up